# VS 2015 editor copy & paste

Tags: visual-studio-2015

if i copy and paste a line in the VS2015 editor, it dumps spaces.
This means a copy of "sin( 34.3 )" becomes "sin(34.3)"
I add this spaces because i suffer on a visual issue called crowding.

regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When nothing is selected, **Edit** - **Copy** immediately followed by **Edit** - **Paste** duplicates the current line. It preserves spaces unless the caret is near them.

To paste the line in another place in a file without reformatting, you can use the following C# command for my [Visual Commander](https://vlasovstudio.com/visual-commander/) extension:

```
    DTE.ExecuteCommand("Edit.LineFirstColumn");
    EnvDTE.TextSelection ts = DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection as EnvDTE.TextSelection;
    ts.Insert(System.Windows.Clipboard.GetText());
```